# Perl XPath to the value of a form input field

Tags: html, perl, xpath

Shortened example of some html:

```
<input name="some_name" id="some_ID" value="The-Value-I-Want" />
```

In Perl,

```
//input[contains(@id, 'some')]/@value
```

Gives me:

```
value="The-Value-I-Want"
```

But all I REALLY want is :

```
"The-Value-I-Want"
```

I would have thought:

```
//input[contains(@id, 'some')]/@value/text
```

would have done it - but no.  I've tried /@value[text] , /@value/@text , /@value/text() , etc

All the help I find on this issue is in Javascript XPath (or other).  Perl is my language.

Thanks for any help!  :)

Comment: Is `//input[contains(@id, 'some')]/@value` supposed to be an understandable perl statement of some kind?

Comment: Hello @TLP I assumed you would see the XPath statement and I was informing you it works within a Perl module.  Are you being facetious?  Would you have preferred a different notation?  (@daxim got it, below, so I must not have been too far off.)  Thanks for the willingness to help.

Comment: @Ricalsin it would have been useful to mention which module you were using. Several Perl modules implement XPath, possibly in slightly different ways.

Comment: @Ricalsin Well, it's not every day I have to look up english words. =) But no, not facetious, perhaps slightly sardonic. Glad things worked out for you. For future reference, mirod is correct. If you ask a perl question, make sure it's understandable in perl terms, or you will be severely reducing the number of people who can answer your question.

Comment: Thanks! I love the help on StackOverflow, so learning how to work within the system is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string(//input[contains(@id, 'some')]/@value)
```

Tested with libxml2. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string

Comment: Thanks!  Who knew such German acumen could be happy in Aussie-land?  :)